# JavaScript - How to Insert Number to InputBox by using Button

Tags: javascript, numbers, inputbox

Please help, How to insert number into inputbox by Id.

`<input name="table1" type="text" size="1" id="musicstock1"/>`

Would like to insert for example number (5) into this particular input box when button clicked.

So push the "Insert" button number 5 show on inputbox

is this correct?

```
function insert () {
    document.getElementById('musicstock1').innerHTML = "5";
}
```

Thank you in advance

Appericiate for Replys... Please Check @

## http://jsfiddle.net/JxfcH/#

**Not Worked..**

Comment: Please see my edit to learn how to format your code properly for the next time - regarding your question, you were using `innerHTML` instead of `value`.

Answer (score 3):

you must assign value to the "value" attribute of the input box.

```
document.getElementById("musicstock1").value = "5";
```

Comment: Not Working .. Please Check This link..I have tested but no result.

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
function insert () {
    document.getElementById('musicstock1').value = "5";
}
```